# OpenGL + SDL + glew doesn't draw anything after successful initialization

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glew

so I've been searching around for a solution to this for a while but all I could find was pretty outdated. My problem is that after initializing SDL and glew without errors, window opens and anything on other Z than 1, 0 or -1 won't render. And also setting Z to any of those three values doesn't do anything at all. Here is my code. I have both glew and sdl included in header and the loop method is the main program loop.

```
#include "Controller.h"

int Controller::loop() {
    // Initialize
    if(!init())
        return -1;

    SDL_Event _event;

    // Main loop
    while(_running) {
        // Loop through all input
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&_event))
            event(_event);
        // Game logic
        step();
        // Game drawing
        draw();
    }

    // End game
    end();
    return 0;
}

bool Controller::init() {
    // Initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
        return false;

    // Create window
    if ((_mainWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("GAME", 200, 200, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL)) == NULL)
        return false;

    // Create context
    _mainContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(_mainWindow);

    // Make it active
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(_mainWindow, _mainContext);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);

    // Initialize glew
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}

void Controller::event(SDL_Event& _event) {
    switch(_event.type) {
    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        switch (_event.key.keysym.sym) {
        case SDLK_ESCAPE:
            _running = false;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Key has been pressed." << std::endl;
        }
    default:
        break;
    }
    _world[_currentWorld].event(_event);
}

void Controller::step() {
    _world[_currentWorld].step();
}

void Controller::draw() {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -0.5f, -4.0f);    // A
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -0.5f, -4.0f);    // B
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.5f, -4.0f);    // C

    glEnd();

    //_world[_currentWorld].draw();
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(_mainWindow);
}

void Controller::end() {
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(_mainContext);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(_mainWindow);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> anything on other Z than 1, 0 or -1 won't render.

In OpenGL's normalized device coordinate system, the *viewing volume* is just the normalized cube going from -1 to 1 along all three dimensions.

Since you do not apply any transformations, you basically directly draw in NDC space (actually, it would be clip space, but that one will be identical to NDC if your input w coordinate is 1 everythere, and it is by default). As a result, setting z to < -1.0 or > 1.0 will result in the vertices lying outside of the viewing volume. Any values in-between (not just 0.0) should work, though.

> And also setting Z to any of those three values doesn't do anything at all.

I'm not 100% sure that I understand that question right. I think you expect that objects should appear smaller the farther you move them away along z. But the GL will *always* do an orthogonal (non-perspective) projection, by simply rasterizing in the xy-plane. You have to do some perspectivee *transformation* if you want the perspective effect, and typically, that is done via a 4x4 homogenous projection matrix.

I would recommend you to learn the basics of linear algebra and homogenous spaces / projective transformations first, before trying to dive into render APIs like OpenGL or D3D.

Also, there are a few issues with your code:

You request the GL context version *after* you created the context, which will have no effect (it will only tell SDL what to do the next time it creates a GL context). YOu also seem to request a "modern" OpenGL version, 3.3. However, the code you are using for drawing is *deprecated* in modern GL, and those features are completely removed in core profiles. If you start learning GL nowadays, I strongly recommend learn modern OpenGL instead, and not this obsolete cruft from 20 years ago. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://alfonse.bitbucket.org/oldtut/), it also deals with some aspects of the maths.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've put this code together from multiple tutorials and in none I found was everything I needed to know. I totally forgot about that also the Z attribute has range from 0 to 1. I didn't want to go into transformation before being able to draw a simple triangle. And also all the tutorial I found were this old style drawing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any transformation matrices. Hence, the range of visible z is [-1, 1]. If you specify values out of this, the according parts will be clipped away (and will not be visible).